# Why is chrome not showing the images and loading the css when print using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, google-chrome

This is my javascript, to print a particular div. It works well in IE and Mozilla. But I could see only the text without any styles and images. Why is it ?

```
var originalContents;
        function printDiv() {

            if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('subcontent');
                var WindowObject = window.open('../print.aspx', 'popUpWindow', 'height=750,width=650,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
                WindowObject.document.write('<html><body><link href="/Scripts/style_print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><table><tr><td><div id="logo"></div></td></tr><tr><td align="left"><div id="siteloader"></div></td></tr></table>' + DocumentContainer.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
                WindowObject.document.close(); 
                WindowObject.print();
                WindowObject.close();
            }
            else {
                originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
                var printable = document.getElementById('subcontent');
                document.body.innerHTML = printable.innerHTML;
                printCoupon();
            }
        }

        function printCoupon() {
            window.print();
            endPrintCoupon();
        }

        function endPrintCoupon() {
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents; 
        }
```

Comment: How are the images fetched?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad Images are fetched from CSS

Comment: Is the css loaded and getting applied for the div and also is the url for the image getting loaded?

Comment: On my actual page, the image is loading and all the CSS are applied. When I click the Print button, it opens the default print window of chrome which is missing all the styles. I could not inspect element in the print page of chrome. In IE and Mozilla, the images are loading and the CSS are applied. The problem is only in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

WindowObject.close();
comment this line and recheck in chrome. I had same issue, now resolved by commenting this line.